# How to access the variable outside from the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to access the variable outside from the interface. In this Example2 code, I was expecting results as same as Example1. Suggest me how to do it?

```
// Example 1
class Sample1{
    data?:string;
}

const d1 = new Sample1()
d1.data = "hai"
console.log(d1)// Result Sample1 { data: 'hai' }

// Example 2
interface Sample2{
    dat1?:any;
}

class Sample3 implements Sample2{
    dat1:any
   constructor(dat1:Sample2){
        this.dat1 = dat1
    }
}

const d2 = new Sample3({dat1:"hai"})
console.log(d2) // Sample3 { dat1: { dat1: 'hai' } }
```

Comment: You only assign `this.user` and never assign anything to `this.dat1`, so it's never filled in and thus never exists.

Comment: I have edited my question could you please check again.

Comment: You assign an object to `dat1`, so you get the whole object. If only want to assign the value `'hai'` then you need to do `this.dat1 = dat1.dat1`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Use the spread operator:

```
// Example 2
interface Sample2{
    dat1?:any;
}

class Sample3 implements Sample2{
    dat1:any
   constructor(dat:Sample2){
        this.dat1 = {...dat}
    }
}

const d2 = new Sample3({dat1:"hai"})
```

Comment: This will be invalid, since the constructor parameter should be a `Sample2` conforming object, not a string. [Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFEA8EMFsAcA2BTUAmAUASwHYBdkAnAM2gGNUBlOJZNAbw1GdABNo8BGAfgC5ocATwDcGAL4YMZRNADOs0NQQoAzKCzLksZPgVLaDJi3Zd+Qo6DIB7HLLyEArmTxXCAChOde+lGgCUjCxBoHgAFliyAHSeoAC8bBycFqASElI2dmxocaA4yADuijSqbgBEodBYpX7CQA)

Comment: Oh. My fault. You are right @VLAZ. I changed my answer :-)